# Fail to install ADT Plugin

Tags: android

Hey i'm trying to install it and i've tried everything.

- **I've downloaded the EE Eclipse as i saw in some forum**
- **Changed https to http, still won't install**
- **Tried manual installation, wont install**
- **Tried to run as Administrator, no good**

I Get the same error :

```
 Unexpected Error.  Could not process the request. Check the error log for details.
```

in the log i see :

```
org/sat4j/minisat/core/AssertingClauseGenerator
```

org/sat4j/minisat/core/AssertingClauseGenerator

I'm using Windows 7 32 bit, installed JDK
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end i just downloaded Eclipse Helios instead of Indigo and that did the trick.